# Difference between V2 and V3 in share point

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, web-part, list-view-web-part

Difference between

`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2"`

AND

`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3"`

in SharePoint web part provision?

Comment: Any help from my pointer?

Answer (score 2):

[The difference between .dwp and .webpart](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/08/21/the-difference-between-dwp-and-webpart.aspx)

> The difference is .dwp was the file extension used in version 2 of
>   SharePoint and .webpart is a new extension used in version 3.  Inside
>   the files, the schemas are different and it is indicated as such by
>   the version number on the xmlns attribute.